# PHP Constants in includes

Tags: php, include, constants

I have defined the root of my site as a constant in the config file:

```
define('SITE_ROOT', 'http://folder/site/home');
```

I have then tried to use the constant in an include string, but it doesn't seem to work:

```
<? include (SITE_ROOT.'/incs/header.php'); ?>
```

But when I use it to include an image it works fine:

```
<img src="<?= SITE_ROOT ?>/img/banner.png"/>
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because `include` works with local filesystem paths, not URLs. Even if you enable including files through HTTP (which is in general a bad idea and a big security risk) with the appropriate configuration, you would still have other issues.

What you want to do instead is define another constant in your config file:

```
define('DIR_ROOT', dirname(__FILE__)); // DIR_ROOT points to where the config is
```

And then

```
<? include (DIR_ROOT.'/incs/header.php'); ?>
```

As an aside, you should never *ever* embed unescaped data inside HTML. Your `<img>` example should instead read like

```
<img src="<?= htmlspecialchars(SITE_ROOT); ?>/img/banner.png"/>
```

Note that the above is still not correct as written because the first three args of [`htmlspecialchars`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) should always be explicitly specified. And since that is cumbersome, in practice you would wrap calls to it with a function of your own that also has a nice short name (this is one of the exceptional cases where an one-character name would be a good idea).